# HTML form method GET

Tags: html, http

I have a super simple html page, user enters various inputs, clicks submit and a query string is returned to the same page using the HTTP GET form method.

Everything works great, except there is no data for the first two text boxes, or the text area. Am I missing something, or is that how it's supposed to work?

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>User Registration</h3>
    <form action="UserRego.html">
        <p>First Name: 
            <input id="txtFirstName" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>Surname: 
            <input id="txtSurname" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>Gender: 
            <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male" />Male <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Female" />Female
        </p>
    <p>Address: 
        <textarea id="taAddress" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>Which of the following sports do you like watching?</p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Sport" value="Soccer" />Soccer<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="Sport" value="Aussie Rules" />Aussie Rules<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="Sport" value="Rugby League" />Rugby League<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="Sport" value="Rugby Union" />Rugby Union<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="Sport" value="Netball" />Netball<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="Sport" value="Cricket" />Cricket<br />
        <p>How did you hear about us: 
            <select name="slbRef">
                <option value="Internet" selected="selected">Internet</option>
                <option value="Word of Mouth">Word of Mouth</option>
                <option value="Newspaper">Newspaper</option>
        </select></p>
        <button type="reset">Clear</button>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it hasn't `'name'` attr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to add the attribute name="" for them,

this will work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>User Registration</h3>
    <form action="UserRego.html">
        <p>First Name: 
            <input id="txtFirstName" name="txtFirstName" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>Surname: 
            <input id="txtSurname" name="txtSurname" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>Gender: 
            <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male" />Male <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Female" />Female
        </p>
    <p>Address: 
        <textarea id="taAddress" name="taAddress" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>Which of the following sports do you like watching?</p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Sport" value="Soccer" />Soccer<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="Sport" value="Aussie Rules" />Aussie Rules<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="Sport" value="Rugby League" />Rugby League<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="Sport" value="Rugby Union" />Rugby Union<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="Sport" value="Netball" />Netball<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="Sport" value="Cricket" />Cricket<br />
        <p>How did you hear about us: 
            <select name="slbRef">
                <option value="Internet" selected="selected">Internet</option>
                <option value="Word of Mouth">Word of Mouth</option>
                <option value="Newspaper">Newspaper</option>
        </select></p>
        <button type="reset">Clear</button>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah, of course! I knew it was something simple I had missed. Still in the process of learning...Many thanks, I will accept this as the answer when it lets me.